A question about JavaScript with HTML - Clicker mini project
I'm new to programming, I'm studying JavaScript, basic CSS, basic HTML and I'm making a mini "clicker" project where I intend to update every time I learn something new, but I'm having a hard time understanding why the "if" part of the code isn't working.
HTML:


var num = document.getElementById("number");
let numberAdd = 1;
var numberDisplay = 0;

function addNum() {
  numberDisplay += numberAdd;
  num.textContent = numberDisplay;
}

function addUpgrade() {
  numberDisplay -= 10;
  num.textContent -= 10;
  numberAdd++;
}


if (numberDisplay > 10) {
  var disP = document.getElementById("display");
  const newBtn = document.createElement("button");
  newBtn.innerHTML = '<button id="addUp" onclick="addUpgrade()">Upgrade';
  disP.appendChild(newBtn)
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Clicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="display">
    <h1 id="number">0</h1>
    <button id="addNum" onclick="addNumber()">Add</button>
  </div>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



My problem is here, I'm trying to use simple logic: number > 10 ?If true, create a button.
if (numberDisplay > 10) {
    var disP = document.getElementById("display");
    const newBtn = document.createElement("button");
    newBtn.innerHTML = '<button id="addUp" onclick="addUpgrade()">Upgrade';
    disP.appendChild(newBtn)
}

But it's not working
enter image description here

It's "working", the condition is just false so the code therein isn't executed.  (It's false because numberDisplay was just defined and initialized to 0, which is not greater than 10.)  Did you mean to put this logic in a function to be invoked at a later time?  The only function your HTML calls is addNumber which isn't defined here, so it's not clear what exactly you're expecting.

The idea is that every time I click on the “Add” button it adds 1 to “numberDisplay” and this is happening according to the console, it is in the image I posted. Could you explain to me how it could be done the right way ?

The if (numberDisplay) code needs to be inside the addNumber function.

Is addNum supposed to be addNumber?

@Nicollaso: I'm sure there's a duplicate question I'm not finding yet, but basically if you want this if block to execute in one of the functions you define then that code would go inside that function.  If it belongs in multiple functions then you can define it as its own function and call that from other functions.  But as you have it now it executes once, and only once, when the page initially loads.

Anything that's not inside a function only runs once, when the page first loads. It can't depend on variables that are updated when you interact with the page. If you want it to run later, it should be in a function that's called as a result of the interactions.

@Barmar It's an error from when I was converting the code to English and I only realized it now, thanks for letting me know.

Thanks to everyone who responded, now I understand where I went wrong in the code.

I made a runnable snippet that shows the error when you click the button

If you place an if statement inside the event handler to check the number every time the user clicks the button, you can make the if statement work if the number is greater than 10.


const num = document.getElementById("number");
let numberAdd = 1;
let numberDisplay = 0;

const addBtn = document.getElementById("addNum");
addBtn.addEventListener('click', addNumber);

function addNumber() {

  numberDisplay += numberAdd;
  num.textContent = numberDisplay;

  let upgradeBtn = document.getElementById("addUp");

  if (!upgradeBtn) {
    if (numberDisplay > 10) {
      const disP = document.getElementById("display");
      const newBtn = document.createElement("button");

      newBtn.setAttribute("id", "addUp");
      newBtn.addEventListener('click', addUpgrade);
      newBtn.textContent = 'Upgrade';

      disP.appendChild(newBtn)
    }
  }
}

function addUpgrade() {
  numberDisplay -= 10;
  num.textContent -= 10;
  numberAdd++;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Clicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="display">
    <h1 id="number">0</h1>
    <button id="addNum">Add</button>
  </div>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



